execute something on resolve and reject of a promise
I am trying to implement a Promise for the first time. The code I have here works meaning that when beforeRemoveTag is triggered I see the confirm expected and if I hit 'OK' it resolves the promise while with 'Cancel' it reject the promise. So far so good.
new Tagify(input,{
    hooks:{
        beforeRemoveTag: tags => {
            //tags[0].node.classList.add('tagify__tag--loading');
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve() : reject()
            })
        }
    }
});

Now I'd like to add an alert when the promise is resolved and another when the promise is rejected.
So as a pseudocode:
new Tagify(input,{
    hooks:{
        beforeRemoveTag: tags => {
            //tags[0].node.classList.add('tagify__tag--loading');
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve(alert('Removed!') : reject(alert('not removed!')
            })
        }
    }
});

How to do it?

Add a .then() callback to your new promise. The code will run when the promise resolves. You can also add a .catch() callback.

@Pointy just like return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                 confirm(Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?) ? resolve() : reject()             }).then(alert('Removed!')).catch(alert('Not Removed!'))?

I tried it and it just execute both then and catch when promise is either resolved or rejected

No. You have to pass a function to .then(), just as you pass a function to new Promise().  Your code is calling the function and then passing the return value.

What's wrong with the posted code? Assuming confirm(\Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve() : reject()works as expected (it resolves or rejects as expected),confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve(alert('Removed!')) : reject(alert('not removed!'))` should also work as expected. If you get an error with your code, please describe the error and add the error message. It could be the typo (missing parenthesis).

@Pointy If confirm(\Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve() : reject()already works as expected,confirmhas to be blocking (otherwise the promise would resolve or reject too early). In that case, you don't need.thenor.catch`.

It is not really useful to wrap confirm in a promise, since confirm is blocking. I don't see an added value. Instead, avoid using confirm, prompt and alert at all.

@trincot they were used to demonstrate the issue. Actually a sweetalert2 message (not blocking) is used

With a non-blocking code, this confirm(\Remove ${tags[0].data.value} ?`) ? resolve() : reject()` won't work as expected. The promise will be resolved or rejected too early.

That is an essential difference, @Lelio. I suggest you update your question. The behaviour of the code is completely different in that case.

For your code, the alerts should go in the .then (for success) and .catch (for failure), while making sure to pass functions to these.
The resolve or reject methods are for handling the outcome of the promise instead.
Here is a revised version of your code:


new Tagify(input, {
  hooks: {
    beforeRemoveTag: (tags) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value}?`) ? resolve() : reject();
      })
      .then(() => alert('Removed!')) //Passing the function to alert here
      .catch(() => alert('Not removed!'));
    },
  },
});



You can read more about handling promises here
Better still, you could rewrite this code using the async keyword in javascript and handle the states with try-catch


new Tagify(input, {
  hooks: {
    beforeRemoveTag: async (tags) => { // Define the function as asynchronous 
      try {
        const shouldRemove = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          confirm(`Remove ${tags[0].data.value}?`) ? resolve(true) : reject(false);
        });
        if (shouldRemove) alert('Removed!');
      } catch {
        alert('Not removed!'); 
      }
    },
  },
});



